# Associated type error: Cannot assign a value of type '[SpecificType]' to a value of type '[NameOfTypeAlias]'

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, generics

I am trying to create a fairly generic UITableView implementation that can display different types of cells. I'm using associated types to specify the data source type, cell type, and so on. I have most of it working really well, but I am having some trouble subclassing the implementation. I'm showing the least amount of code I can below to get the point across.

Here's my high-level architecture:

```
protocol DGTableViewAble {
  typealias DGTableViewItemType
  ...
  var items: [DGTableViewItemType] { get set }
}

class DGTableView: UITableView, DGTableViewAble {
  typealias DGTableViewItemType = User

  var items: [DGTableViewItemType] = [] { ... }
}

class DGPostsTableView: DGTableView {
  typealias DGTableViewItemType = Post
}

...
```

Things work great when I assign an array of `User` objects to any `DGTableView` instance. For example, this works great:

```
var users: [User] = [...]
var userTableView: DGTableView 

userTableView.items = users
```

However, when I try this:

```
var posts: [Post] = [...]
var postsTableView: DGPostsTableView

postsTableView.items = posts
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot assign a value of type '[Post]' to a value of type '[DGTableViewItemType]'
```

It seems like the compiler has trouble determining the associated types as I have things set up. Any ideas why? Any suggestions on improving the architecture?

Answer (score 1):

Post isn't declaring viewable protocol?

```
class DGPostsTableView: DGTableView, DGTableViewAble {
  typealias DGTableViewItemType = Post
}
```

It will also have to conform to said protocol. Maybe marking the unneeded protocol components as optional could solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You're not inheriting from `DGTableViewAble` in your class interface for `DGPostsTableView`:

```
class DGPostsTableView: DGTableView, DGTableViewAble {
    typealias DGTableViewItemType = Post

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, gents, but that's not it. That leads to a couple of problems: a compiler error that DGPostsTableView doesn't conform to the protocol (presumably because there's no items property). When I declare items, I'm greeted with another compiler error: 'DGTableViewItemType' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context. I've found posts about similar errors, but nothing that's really shed any light on my issues...

Comment: Are you sure that's not it? Maybe you could track down why the type is ambiguous and it could solve your issue?